# Record Changing Cell Value in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a cell whose value is constantly changing through a feed. I want to develop a macro which when activated records the cell value at that instant and pastes it in another cell. Tried finding some formula to do that but no success.

Comment: Try harder and it cant be done using formula.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that with a formula. However, you can write a macro that checks if your cell was changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
...
End Sub
```

If you don't want this type of automation, you could simply add a button to your worksheet which triggers a macro when clicked and does what you are looking for.

To copy the value of a cell into another one, you could use this simple solution:

```
Range("B1").Value = Range("A1").Value
```

This will copy the value of cell A1 into cell B1.